# How to execute JavaScript after a particular div is loaded in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sitecore

I want to get the the elements by class name of a particular div / ul which is coming from server side. But when I am trying to access the element using

`var element=document.getElementsByClassName("Class-Name");`

Its return undefined because : the HTML is still rendering but it is taking time to load that particular UL which is coming from Server side. Need help ?

I have tried :

1. Writing script at the end of HTML code.
2. Tried `window.load=function()`

***UL which is coming from Server (Site-core / CSHTML):***

```
<ul class=" Class-Name carousel-modal__info-list list-unstyled mb-0">
   <li>
      <h6>Space designed by</h6>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6">By me</div>
         <div class="col-6 text-right">Link</div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
</ul>
.
.
.
<script>
window.load = function(){
var element=document.getElementsByClassName("Class-Name");
console.log(element);
}
</script>
```

**Actual Result:** Undefined 
**Expected:** 'elements related to Class'

Comment: Put a `<script>` tag directly after the element.

Comment: can not put because that <ul> is coming from server side with a little delay .

Comment: You need *either* put the script at the end *or* use `onload`. Doing both is not necessary

Comment: How is it coming from ServerSide?, is it using Ajax, if so place that code in your Ajax callback.

Comment: @Avinashnayak what do you mean by "with a little delay"? Is it in the original HTML or added later?

Comment: @Bergi He's probably sending an XHR that sends back that HTML. He's attempting to select the elements before that XHR completes.

Comment: Post the AJAX call that sends back that HTML. You should be selecting the elements when that call completes successfully.

Comment: its coming from content management (site-core). 
first parent  <div> will load then we are calling data from sitecore using 
`data-properties` . so because of that delay script is not getting element.

Answer (score 1):

If this is server side rendering and only this block of code is being fetched from the server, try injecting the script at the end of the page without window.onload.

For example, if following piece of HTML is being fetched,

```
<div id='test'>test</div>
```

You can simply write your script at the end of this page, where your html ends.

```
<div id='test'>test</div>
<script>
var testDiv = document.getElementById ('test');
</script>
```

This script will be executed as soon as the `test` is loaded. So in your case, inject the script below `</ul>`.

Note:
If this particular `ul` is the result of an XHR call, you can add your JavaScript inside success callback of XHR.

`window.onload` is executed when the DOM is loaded completely, with images and other resources. The loading of `ul` in your case is an explicit request, so `window.onload` will not wait for it before execution. See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

If you do not have the access of the HTML source, create a function in your JavaScript and ask the dev who has access to the HTML source to execute your function below end of `ul` tag.

It is clear in your code that `ul` is not loaded when `window.onload` is executed, so you need to inject the script in the source, or make use of callbacks if it's an XHR call.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onload` instead of just `load`.

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward way is to attempt to select those elements when the XHR that sends back that HTML completes and injects the HTML, within the success callback.

Another (and less ideal) way is to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to observe for changes to an elements child list.

```js
// Simulates your AJAX call injecting HTML asynchronously.
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#parent')
    .innerHTML = `
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
    `
}, 500)

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.foo')
  console.log(elems)
})

observer.observe(document.querySelector('#parent'), {
  childList: true
})
```

```html
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

Just make sure your target [browsers support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility) it.